# How do I update the single element of an array present as field in a mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

here is the data structure of orders I have:

```
"data": ["_id": "6465f4925560ee0a22110e2b",
"orderId": "order_Lr589EnE0MQi6e",
"orderedBy": "644f3a451111831a1a641c02",
"orderedItems": [
{
"productId": "643fe2296370aa18d6a41339",
"quantity": 2,
"title": "HP 15s,11th Gen Intel Core i3-1115G4 8GB RAM/512GB SSD 15.6-inch(39.6 cm) Micro-Edge Anti-Glare FHD Laptop/Alexa Built-in/Win 11/Intel UHD Graphics/Dual Speakers/MS Office 2021/1.69 Kg, 15s-fq2673TU",
"brand": "HP",
"image": "https://my-e-site.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/public/images/1681908247-1.jpg",
"price": "40990",
"seller": "643d38cf6102ca00170416b8",
"buyer": "644f3a451111831a1a641c02",
"status": "SHIPPED",
"_id": "6465f4595560ee0a22110e0f"
},
{
"productId": "6446790dac36eb9d31143df1",
"quantity": 1,
"title": "itoys Disney Frozen 2 Activity Ball Pool with Multicolor Balls for Kids (Frozen 2 Tent)",
"brand": "itoys",
"image": "https://my-e-site.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/public/images/1682340105-1.jpg",
"price": "1399",
"seller": "644667817a4612d81b3f037d",
"buyer": "644f3a451111831a1a641c02",
"status": "ORDERED",
"_id": "6465f4635560ee0a22110e1a"
}
],
"deliveryAddress": "testing Refecth 9876543210 ABC flat 99 Amc colony, Abc Streey near Abc College ABC city ABC state 768988",
"paymentStatus": "PREPAID",
"createdAt": "2023-05-18T09:43:10.978Z",
"updatedAt": "2023-05-18T09:43:10.978Z",
"__v": 0
}
]
```

I want to update a single orderedItems status to "intransit"

I have tried using this method.

```
 const data = await Order.findOneAndUpdate({
      "_id": "6465f4925560ee0a22110e2b",    
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "orderedItems.0.status": "SHIPPED"
      }
    },
    {
      multi: false
    })
```

which is updating, but then I want to update the orderedItems based on element id not by array index 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrayFilters: as follow:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
$set: {
 "orderedItems.$[x].status": "SHIPPED"
}
},
{
 arrayFilters: [
{
  "x._id": "6465f4635560ee0a22110e1a"
 }
]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ge0lbJeMRDh)

Comment: Please,accept my answer if you think is the answer you have been looking for ... :)

Comment: You can click on the checkbox on left upper corner of the answer tio accept it , it will become green when accepted